# In NestJs can I prevent multiple providers with the same Injection token?

Tags: nestjs

Suppose I have a setup with two implementations of a service, one for development and one for production:

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'MyService',
      useClass: ProdMyService,
    }
  ],
  exports: ['MyService'],
})
export class ProdModule { }

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'MyService',
      useClass: DevMyService,
    }
  ],
  exports: ['MyService'],
})
export class DevModule { }

@Module({
  controllers: [MyController],
  imports: [ProdModule, DevModule],
})
export class AppModule { }

class MyController {
  constructor(@Inject('MyService') private readonly service: MyServiceInterface) { }
}
```

Is it possible to make NestJs consider the above list of `imports` in `AppModule` a mistake insofar as it's ambiguous which version of `'MyService'` I intended to inject? In the above it seems that it will just choose one of them and then ignore the other.